# Laravel 4 Blade: How to use custom models?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-blade

Normally in Laravel I call a model by creating something like this:

```
class Config extends Eloquent {

protected function getBaseUri() {
    return sprintf(
        "%s://%s%s", isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] != 'off' ? 'https' : 'http', $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], '/project/public/assets/'
    );
}

public static function getBaseImagePath() {
    return $this->getBaseUri() . 'image/';
}

}
```

and call it somewhere in php files like this:

> echo Config::getBaseImagePath();

Now, I'm migrating into .blade.php and I need to call the same function from the model, so I did this somewhere in the blade:

> {{ Config::getBaseImagePath() }}

And it's not working (weird enough, since what I know is all blade doing is convert {{ }} tags to php tags). Can anyone explain how to make this work? Thanks.

Error I'm getting is:

> Call to undefined method
>   Illuminate\Config\Repository::getBaseImagePath()

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using a Laravel class name `Config`.

I don't know why it works in PHP and not in Blade, but it shouldn't.

So you have some options:

1) Change the `Config` Laravel alias in app/config/app.php

2) Change your `Config` class name.

3) Create a namespace for your classes:

```
<? namespace MyName\Services

class Config extends Eloquent {

    protected function getBaseUri() {
        return sprintf(
            "%s://%s%s", isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] != 'off' ? 'https' : 'http', $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], '/project/public/assets/'
        );
    }

    public static function getBaseImagePath() {
        return $this->getBaseUri() . 'image/';
    }

}
```

Execute

```
composer dump-autoload
```

And use it

```
{{ \MyName\Services\Config::getBaseImagePath() }}
```

Answer (score 2):

In your code

```
{{ Config::getBaseImagePath() }}
```

It's pointing to the laravel's `Illuminate\Config\Repository` class where this method is not available. Change the name or use `namespace`. Also, you can't use `$this` in a `static` method, instead you can use

```
public static function getBaseImagePath() {
    return static::getBaseUri() . 'image/';
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, yeah it is because the class' name in the namespace, forgot to change it into soemthing else